# Convert CSV file into sequence using Mahout 0.10 for classification using random forest

Tags: java, csv, mahout, random-forest

I have a CSV file which I would like to convert to a SequenceFile to use in  classification task using random forest algorithm. How can I do this using
mahout 0.10 and netbeans?

my data contains numeric and nominal values:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00296/

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSV parser in [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to read your files.

I had a quick look at your file and you can convert these "no", "yes" and "none" values to boolean/null very easily:

```
ObjectRowListProcessor rowProcessor = new ObjectRowListProcessor();

rowProcessor.convertFields(Conversions.toBoolean("yes", "no")).set("metformin-rosiglitazone","metformin-pioglitazone","change","diabetesMed","readmitted")); //and all other fields where this makes sense.

rowProcessor.convertFields(Conversions.toLowerCase(), Conversions.toNull("none", "?")).set("another field", "and another field");

CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//the rowProcessor will be executed here.
parser.parse(YOUR_INPUT_HERE);

List<Object[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();
```

If you prefer objects with annotations, you can use a `BeanListProcessor` as detailed [here](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers#using-annotations-to-map-your-java-beans). Maybe that will be the best approach for you case.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).